# Apply animation script to different Div/img

Tags: javascript, html, css

Need to apply the animateScript() function to different images/divs on mouseover. i think i just need to change my document.querySelector but im not sure how to do so so that it applies to one of the 4 different images.

```
let tID; //we will use this variable to clear the setInterval()
//let x = event.clientX, y = event.clientY, elementMouseIsOver = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);

function stopAnimate() {
    clearInterval(tID);
} //end of stopAnimate()

function animateScript() {
    let position = 80; //start position for the image slicer
    let height = 0;
    const interval = 190; //180 ms of interval for the setInterval()
    const diff = 80; //diff as a variable for position offset
    const next_row = 110;
    let elements = document.querySelectorAll(':hover');

    tID = setInterval(() => {
        document.querySelector(".avatar").style.backgroundPosition = `-${position}px -${height}px`;
        //we use the ES6 template literal to insert the variable "position"
        if (height < 220)
        {
            if (position < 720) {
                position = position + diff;
                console.log(position);
            }
            else if (position == 720){
                //console.log("height");
                position = 80;
                height = next_row + height;
                console.log("height: ", height);
            }
        }
        else {
            if (position < 400) {
                position = position + diff;
                console.log(position);
            }
            else if (position == 480){
                position = 80;
                height = 0;
                console.log("height: ", height);
            }
        }
        //reset the position to 256px, once position exceeds 1536px
    }, interval); //end of setInterval
} //end of animateScript()
```

Comment: Just pass in the element you want to animate as a script parameter.

Comment: thanks, i ended up passing in the element as param for the script... seems so obvious now.

Answer (score 0):

You're hard-coding the `.avatar` selector, which will always get the first element with that class, so you're correct that that will need to change.

One easy solution would be to pass the hovered element into your function.

```
const handleMouseEnter = (e) => {
    const el = e.target;
    animateScript(el);
}

element.addEventListner("mouseenter", handleMouseEnter);

function animateScript(element) {
    [...]
    tID = setInterval(() => {
        element.style.backgroundPosition = `whatever style`;
        [...]
    }, interval);
}
```